# How to make country-wise WordPress posts

Tags: wordpress

I am designing a website of prices of products which have different prices in every country. Let's say I am making a post named Frigidaire 18 Bottle Wine Cooler price in USA.

Now this product have different price in Mexico, Greece, India, London etc.

I want to make all posts same in every country accept prices (as taxonomy).

If I have 15 countries, this one post should be published 15 times and in every country' post only price and post title will be changed?

Should I develop custom plugin or you suggest me to do, or I just make all of countries posts normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is use custom fields, something like **More Fields** or **Advanced Custom Fields**, both free plugins.

You create several custom fields named:

```
price-en
price-gr
price-in
price-mx
```

and populate them in each post. Note that you only need **one post** per product.

When you display the product, you get the current language, say `gr` (for Greece) and display the field:

```
get_post_meta('price-' . getLanguage());
```

Where `getLanguage()` is a PHP function to get the current language code.

That's it, you don't need taxonomies or multiple posts per product.

Comment: tnx, how do i embed country name in title of the post ? using get post meta or something else ?

Comment: You don't embed the country name in the post, you get it on frontend from another variable. Are you using a plugin for the multilanguage part?